# Return type of void *, is it different in C++ and in C?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, malloc

I'm reading this source: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/4.2/doc/examples/hw_decode.c#L120

and in the line 120 it has:

```
buffer = av_malloc(size);
```

where buffer is defined as this:

```
uint8_t *buffer = NULL;
```

Well, [av_malloc](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/group__lavu__mem.html#ga9722446c5e310ffedfaac9489864796d) is defined as this:

```
void* av_malloc (size_t size)
```

In C++ I get the following error for line 120:

```
a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "uint8_t *"
```

but it looks like it works in C.

What is happening?

I also found an example code where it casts to `int16_t *`. How do I know for which value to cast?

Comment: Are you really asking if one thing in `c` is the same as something else from another language?

Comment: In C a `void*` pointer can be assigned to/from any pointer type without a cast. In C++, an explicit cast to the actual type is required. (so you hinted at the answer in the last sentence of your question)

Comment: Helpful reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Ok, understood, but in C++, what should I cast to? uint8_t, uint16_t, etc? What are the consequences

Comment: If the LHS of the assignment is a `uint8_t *`, then you need to cast the result of `av_malloc()` to a `uint8_t *`.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs In the case of `malloc` there are no consequenes, `malloc`ed pointers are designed to be cast like this. In other situations there could be conseuqnces, it depends on many things. The C++ thing to do is to use `new` instead of `malloc`.